# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.DBConcurrencyException' occured

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a program using VB 2012 with microsoft access 2013 database in the middle of the coding I encountered this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.DBConcurrencyException' occured..."

Can anyone help me get through this error.

Thanks

Comment: Usually copy and pasting your code is a better option. As for your issue, I cannot help.

Comment: Your `DataSet` contains two version of the data: original and current.  A concurrency violation occurs when the original data in the `DataSet` doesn't match the data in the database when you try to save.  The legitimate reason for it occurring is that another user has updated the database in the meantime, in which case your application has to notify the user and decide what to do about it, e.g. retrieve the data and edit again. You can also mess up your data and cause this, e.g. make changes, call `AcceptChanges`, make more changes and then try to save.